# Excel set color of line graph based on color of cells

Tags: excel, colors, linegraph

So I have a set of data, see picture below.
[image]

I want the color of the line graph to be the same as the background color of the corresponding row. The top 10 should be green, and the bottom 10 red in this example. This is something I will continuously be doing, with sometimes large data sets, so individually selecting the color of each line is not a viable option.

Can anyone please help me out?
-Tim

Comment: Would you consider VBA macro for this. What if the color is hard coded inside the macro. My sample code that worked is as below:

Comment: `    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this may get you most of the way there.

- Iterate through the `SeriesCollection` of the `Chart` and grab the `Formula` of each `Series`.
- Get the reference to the source data (3rd portion of the formula) with `Split`.
- Set the `ForeColor.RGB` of each `Series` equal to the `Interior.Color` of the data range associated with it.

---

```
Sub ColorMyChart()
    Dim myChart As ChartObject
    Set myChart = Sheet1.ChartObjects("Chart 1")

    With myChart.Chart
        Dim i As Integer

        For i = 1 To .SeriesCollection.Count

            Dim dataAddress As String
            ' takes a formula like =SERIES(Sheet1!$A$2,Sheet1!$B$1:$K$1,Sheet1!$B$2:$K$2,1)
            ' and returns Sheet1!$B$2:$K$2
            dataAddress = Split(.SeriesCollection(i).Formula, ",")(2)

            Dim dataColor As Long
            ' assumes the data range all has the same color
            dataColor = Sheet1.Range(dataAddress).Interior.Color

            .SeriesCollection(i).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = dataColor
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```